# Does Pentaho allow the "Filter rows" step to load a list of values?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-cde

I need to filter the rows of a table according to a list `DOM_LABEL` that contains the correct values that should match the ones present in the column `label`.

`DOM_LABEL = ['Microsoft', 'Apple', 'Lenovo']` this list is contained inside a csv file.

The problem is that some rows have incorrect values such as `'Samsung', 'HP', etc`. I don't know the incorrect values present, so by filtering the rows by `label` values not contained in `DOM_LABEL` helps me analyze the problem better.

However, the `Filter rows` step does not allow me to load a list of values. And manually adding them into the step is gruesome because the `DOM_LABEL` contains more than 100 values. Is there a way to load those values into the `Filter rows` step?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best sollution in this case, if I'm understanding the issue correctly, is by setting up a field beforehand, which checks if the value is in the list and then filter rows on that field.

How to do this?

Load the data from the csv in a seperate step (csv input). Then in your mainflow BEFORE the filter row step, us a 'stream lookup' step to find the value from your main flow column in the csv. retrieve the column i which you lookup the value. Then in the filter rows, just check if the lookedup value is empty or not.

[image: Layout of flow]

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to understand my issue correctly. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Then please check the answer, to help future users? :D

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](https://pentaho-public.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/EAI/pages/371558145/Filter+Rows), you can use the **Filter** step with a List of values.

You need to select '**IN LIST**' in Functions and then put values as String seperated by a semicolon (;). This also works on numeric values like integers. The step return *True* if value is in the LIST.

e.g : `Microsoft;Apple;Lenovo`

[Screenshot of step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usmpz.png)

Considering you're a using a **CSV file Input**, you must concat fields using the **Group by** step before using the Filter and make sure to seperate using semicolon (;).

You can add a **Constant** and group by the constant field to concatenate the label.